# Convert NSNumber into String Swift 2

Tags: swift, ios9

**To convert NSNumber Into String Swift 2**

```
let tempNumber = userInfoDict.valueForKey("designation") as! NSNumber
  let str2 = tempNumber.stringValue
```

**Accurate result**

Comment: This isn't really a question.

Comment: let stringTemp = String(format: "%d", tempNumber.integerValue)

Answer (score 16):

Since the numeric result is supposed to be an `Int` anyway you can omit the `NSNumber` detour.

```
let tempNumber = userInfoDict.valueForKey("designation") as! Int 
let stringTemp = String(tempNumber)
```

Side note: Since `userInfoDict` seems to be a dictionary, don't use the key-value coding method `valueForKey:` unless you really need the special functionality.
Either use key subscripting (recommended) `userInfoDict["designation"]` or `objectForKey:`

Comment: It says "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(NSNumber?)'"

Answer (score 12):

You'll have to format the NSNumber's doubleValue member to a string before outputting.

```
let tempNumber:NSNumber = 6.0
let s:String = String(format:"%f", tempNumber.doubleValue) //formats the string to accept double/float
print(s)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can refer the following code to see how NSNumber can be converted into NSString.

```
 let a = 10
let aString = String(a)
```

Its better to avoid complicated codes for simple stuffs.